# What is the best way to present data from a very large resultset?

Tags: java, hibernate, web-applications, jdbc

I'm writing a report view of an audit trail, and I need to display this in a .jsp. What's the "best" way to get the data from the database to the screen?

We're using Spring for dependency injection, Data Access Objects, and Hibernate.
I can use hibernate or straight jdbc for this report.

If I load all the records into memory I run out of memory.

Any ideas that don't involve running the query in the jsp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like this is a natural place to use pagination of your Hibernate results -- run the query at the Servlet level, and paginate results in a way similar to how this person describes:

http://blog.hibernate.org/Bloggers/Everyone/Year/2004/Month/08/Day/14#pagination

This is the easiest method of implementing Hibernate pagination I've seen...

Answer (score 2):

The [Display Tag Library](http://displaytag.org) is very good at presenting paginated result sets in servlets or portlets. But it normally works with the whole list loaded into memory. So you will have to do a little work to get it to work with paginated result sets by implementing the `org.displaytag.pagination.PaginatedList` interface. There is a [tutorial](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/tut_externalSortAndPage.html) on the Display Tag web site. There isn't very much to the tutorial but then again implementing the interface is pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

Just use paging and only load a certain number of rows on the page at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to use scroll() to stream one row at the time.